# Is there a library or hassle-free class to determine if user is on WiFi or not?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, networking, wifi

I have heard or a Reachability class that checks if user has internet. But is there a simple way to check if user is connected to WiFi? It is because my app would initiate a large download from my server but I want to do this only if user is on WiFi to reduce cellular data usage.

I remember long time ago I came across a single class file that had bool property like isConnectedToWiFi but forgot the name.

Comment: you could use this: https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

Answer (score 2):

Using `Reachability` class is the most simple way of doing it. 
Try this:

```
- (BOOL)isWifiOn {
    Reachability* wifiReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];

    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [wifiReachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    return (networkStatus==ReachableViaWiFi);
}
```